# Convert from one date style to another

Tags: sql, date, formatting

So I have a column in a table that is of type DateTime and are in this style '2013-10-15 11:39:59.137' (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss:mmm). I am trying to convert to this format (dd/mm/yyyy) '15/10/2013'. I have tried things like this `CONVERT(DATETIME,[MyColumnName],103)` 103 being the style that I want, but this just displays the exact same thing. I have also tried converting to `nvarchar(50)` and then converting to `datetime` with my desired style but I then get this error 'The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.', I am unsure of what this means. Is there anyway in which it is possible to change the style of a date.

Answer (score 1):

A `DateTime` will always be displayed as such.

If you want to change the way it is displayed you need to convert it to `VARCHAR`:

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),[MyColumnName],103)
```

Now, this is for display reasons. If you need to convert back to datetime, you need to provide once more the format:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),GETDATE(),103),103)
```

Comment: This worked great when converting to a varchar but ideally I need this as a date and when converting back I get the error as shown in question or it displays again in a different style.

Comment: This doesn't return just date but thanks for response, I have found an answer just needed to set date format to desired formawt.

Answer (score 1):

If the result is a datetime type again, it show's up with the default representation. If you use varchar as representation it shows up. Here an example:

```
select CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),103)
```

may this explains it

```
declare @a varchar(10)
select @a=CONVERT(varchar(10),getdate(),103)
print @a
select convert(datetime,@a,103) as 'Datetime', CONVERT(varchar(10),convert(datetime,@a,103),103) as Text
```

Comment: Thanks this works but theres still an issue, see my comment to 'jyparask'